# How to rename/change network interface name on RedHat Core OS?

Tags: linux, redhat, coreos

I have installed Red Hat core os network interface name and my network interface name comes as ens1f1,ens1f2..etc. I want to change/rename it to eth1, eth2. How can I achieve this?

```
sh-4.4# ifconfig 
ens1f0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 40:a6:b7:43:c8:70  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens1f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 40:a6:b7:43:c8:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens1f2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 40:a6:b7:43:c8:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Also I don't see ens1f1 interface file at  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens1f1 location

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about software development. Please post questions about basic computer usage to https://superuser.com.

Comment: ...but possible what you want is https://blog.hostonnet.com/coreos-disable-consistent-network-device-naming

Answer (score 0):

In order to rename your NIC, you will need to bring it down.

```
$ sudo ifdown ens1f0
```

Once down, you may now rename the card

```
$ sudo ip link set ens1f0 name eth0
```

Rename the config file

```
$ sudo mv /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens1f0 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

Confirm the NIC is available

```
$ ip a
```

Edit the config file

```
$ hwaddr=$(ip a | sed -n '/eth0/{n;s/[^0-9]*\(.*\)/\1/p}')
$ sudo sed -i '\#NAME\|DEVICE#{s/ens1f0/eth0/}' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
$ sudo sed -i "s/\(HWADDR=\).*/\1$hwaddr/" /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

Bring the NIC back up

```
$ sudo ifup eth0
```

Comment: Hi,

Directory "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/" does not contain the RHCOS network interface file "ifcfg-ens1f0". In that case how should I rename the config file as you mentioned in step3. Any alternative way to do this?

Comment: @user3115222 Does https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/consistent-network-interface-device-naming_configuring-and-managing-networking help?